# Cannot type "dot" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I literally cannot type . in Visual Studio Code. This error pops up : 
command 'java.project.addToSourcePath' not found

My keybindings.json looks like this right now.

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    {
        "key": "oem_6",
        "command": "javascript.goToProjectConfig"
    },
    {
        "key": "oem_period",
        "command": "java.project.addToSourcePath"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+p",
        "command": "java.project.create"
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you using any extensions such as [debugger for java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug&ssr=false)?  Maybe try turning them off and trying it.

Comment: Or try another type of file, since this reads as if it would be java-specific. Create a small Python or C file perhaps.

Comment: Nope, the error is overall in Visual Studio Code. I updated my post with my keybindings.json

Answer (score 1):

delete these lines,then you could type dot

```
{
    "key": "oem_period",
    "command": "java.project.addToSourcePath"
},
```